# why response time is so long while file is fetched from cache?

Tags: performance, caching, firebug

I am using firebug to trace why a report take so long to response, but very confusing about the timeline of the firebug. I can see a gif file is fetched from cache, but the time send mostly on is waiting! If the picture is fetched from cache why the waiting time is so long? Thanks guys.

this is the time line, time is wast mostly on waiting

[image: time line]

```
the cache tab of text is below:
Last Modified   Mon Nov 07 2011 10:34:28 GMT+0800 (China Standard Time)
Last Fetched    Fri Nov 11 2011 08:25:48 GMT+0800 (China Standard Time)
Expires Mon Jan 02 2012 20:36:26 GMT+0800 (China Standard Time)
Data Size   1558
Fetch Count 5
Device  disk
```

Comment: Are you it is taken from the cache?

Comment: Date: Mon, 07 Nov 2011 22:26:43 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.14 (Win32) mod_ssl/2.2.17 OpenSSL/0.9.8l
Last-Modified: Thu, 22 Apr 2010 18:07:00 GMT
Etag: "2000000016ceb-332-484d72d519900"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 818
Content-Type: image/gif

Comment: Where does this snippet come from? I assume from Firebug. Webservers can be configured to transmit a 'Last-Modified' date with HTTP responses. So what you see might simply be that. And not a statement that the gif was fetched from cache. Though I am no Firebug or Firefox expert.

Comment: Have you got a screen grab you could share?

Comment: Was a solution for this ever found?  I am experiencing the same problem :(

Comment: I guess is the problem of firefox.